# Is $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ Riemann integrable on [0,1]?

Tags: real-analysis

We need to consider it as improper integral, and am pretty sure it is R.I . I got a hint that I could use an alternating test to prove it,but not sure how. Is it enough to show the integral is finite? any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: To be Riemann integrable, it is necessary that the function be bounded. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/610054/148510

Comment: It exists as an improper Riemann integral. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1948873/improper-integral-of-sin1-x-x-from-0-to-1-vs-lebesgue-integral